# COM Word --> Get all ContentControls

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I want to get all ContentControls of a Word-Document. Currently I use following function to do this.

```
    private static List<ContentControl> GetAllContentControls(Document wordDocument)
    {
        if (null == wordDocument)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("wordDocument");

        List<ContentControl> ccList = new List<ContentControl>();

        Range rangeStory;
        foreach (Range range in wordDocument.StoryRanges)
        {
            rangeStory = range;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (ContentControl cc in rangeStory.ContentControls)
                    {
                        ccList.Add(cc);
                    }
                }
                catch (COMException) { }
                rangeStory = rangeStory.NextStoryRange;

            }
            while (rangeStory != null);
        }
        return ccList;
    }
```

The Problem is to get Contentcontrols in text-fields, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it

```
    private static List<ContentControl> GetAllContentControls(Document wordDocument)
    {
        if (null == wordDocument)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("wordDocument");

        List<ContentControl> ccList = new List<ContentControl>();

        Range rangeStory;
        foreach (Range range in wordDocument.StoryRanges)
        {
            rangeStory = range;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (ContentControl cc in rangeStory.ContentControls)
                    {
                        ccList.Add(cc);
                    }

                    foreach (Shape shapeRange in rangeStory.ShapeRange)
                    {
                        foreach (ContentControl cc in shapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.ContentControls)
                        {
                            ccList.Add(cc);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (COMException) { }
                rangeStory = rangeStory.NextStoryRange;

            }
            while (rangeStory != null);
        }
        return ccList;
    }
```